# Horizontal margin over each section?

Tags: sectioning, rules

How can I draw a horizontal margin over each section?

This is what I want to achieve (horizontal line respecting margins)

[image]

Cheers

Comment: The image looks like part of a resume. Is that the intent? Do you have restrictions in terms of the sectional packages you can use? How about setting up a draft document to show us your use-case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\titlerule\vskip3pt}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\section{test numbered section}
\section*{test unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the settings according to your needs.